# Remove value from HTML5 date input using TestCafe?

Tags: html, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I can't seem to remove the value in an [HTML5 date input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) with TestCafe after it's been set. I've tried `typeText` and `pressKey` so far; `typeText` works for setting a new date but can't input an empty string, while using delete and backspace with `pressKey` doesn't remove the value as it does when manually performing the same action. I also can't/don't know how to click the x on the field itself.

Is there something I'm missing/doing wrong, or is this not possible?

#### typeText

```js
test('typeText', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#dateField', '', { replace: true });

    await t
        .expect(Selector('#dateField').value).eql('');
});
```

`1) The "text" argument is expected to be a non-empty string, but it was "".`

#### pressKey

```js
test('pressKey', async t => {
    await t
        .click('#dateField')
        .pressKey('delete'); // 'backspace' also does not work

    await t
        .expect(Selector('#dateField').value).eql('');
});
```

`1) AssertionError: expected '2019-05-02' to deeply equal ''`

Comment: Do you by chance have an example website that has the type of Date input you are working with?  Is it like a Date picker?  Or just a simple text area/box?

Comment: @TallKU https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date - the input I want to test is just about identical to that first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [TestCafe's typing formats](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/type-text.html#typing-into-datetime-color-and-range-inputs) for HTML5 inputs, you can use the `typeText` action the following way:

```js
test('test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#start', '2017-12-23')
        .expect(Selector('#start').value).eql('2017-12-23')
 
        .typeText('#start', '    -  -  ')
        .expect(Selector('#start').value).eql('');
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I hadn't thought that entering the value like that would translate properly.